# Why are these WMS/WFS layers not appearing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms, wfs

WFS and WMS layers are not appearing when connecting to servers.  I am using QGIS 2.0 and am attempting to connect to:
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=a0ae91856e3c450996d42d53474a1cad

The layers appear in the layer window but no data appears.

Comment: You can see from the WMS GetCapabilities response (https://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/Spatial/SDM.wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&) that the layers are scale layered `ScaleHint`

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting "200" type responses from their web server so it's sending and gives a valid GetCapabilities document.

http://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/SPATIAL/SDM.wms

But it looks like GetMap requests are sending nothing *(ie, a blank image or no results to return for the bounding box requested)*. This is also seen when loading that layer into ArcGIS Online.

To me, what this suggests is that they have a WFS/WMS server running, but that server can't find data on their end *(ie, maybe data changed location on the servers hard disk or they have some funky url rewriting going on - could be a simple fix, but they need to be made aware)*.

I would let the data maintainer know of this issue so it can be looked in to.

Comment: you may need to zoom in to see anything if it is scale dependant

Comment: @iant +1, that's something to look at too!

Comment: You just need to read the GetCap. response to see that scale laying is in force.